# spring boot embedded tomcat logs debug level EOFException & ClosedChannelException when handling request

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, eofexception

**environment:**
spring boot 
react

**root log level:**
debug(not default level info), so the spring boot embedded tomcat debug message will be logged when running.

when web browser requests be handled, some debug exception messages about tomcat always are logged,like below:

[image: eofexception]

[image: ClosedChannelException]

Although debug exception occurs, the business is not affected. So, i didn't find the exception util changed the root log level from info to debug.

Comment: They are logged on debug for a reason...

Comment: EOFException occurs first, then ClosedChannelException in the same thread, but i can't find more useful info. no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: It isn't an exception... That is why it is logged at DEBUG level. If it would be critical it would have been logged at ERROR and our application would probably have blown up.